# Duplicating CoreData records with iCloud sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

When core data syncs with iCloud, occasionally all of my records are doubled. I believe this happens on reinstall, where the app has not yet synced data, creates a new data set, and then iCloud syncs and there are double of each record for each model.

Is there a way to prevent this sort of behavior? Right now I'm checking every model on load and data sync for duplication, but this seems messy and hackish.

Comment: I check to see if the file has been created in iCloud already and if not then create the initial data set.  You have the same issue if two devices run your app, the first one creates the initial database instance and loads seed data.  The next device would need to check if the file already exists in iCloud and if so skip the loading of initial seed data.  Of course if the user starts the app up while both are disconnected then your going to have to deal with the situation when the user decides to connect them.  Kind of messy but maybe ask the user which version to keep.

Comment: Are you syncing using Core Data directly, or some other framework that acts as an intermediary? Two that I've recently come across that might make this easier for you are [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) and [MMRecord](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMRecord).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Trying to use just an iCloud store is folly. Data *must* be stored both locally and in iCloud, or you will run into serious problems.

Use [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) if you want core data.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud transfers data between devices asynchronously, and there can be quite some time between when you add data to the iCloud container, and when it actually gets transferred. Metadata is transferred between devices faster, but even this can be quite delayed.

The reason this is important is that you can never do a test on one device that will guarantee that data has not already been added to iCloud. One device may have seeded data, but not yet begun to upload its files/metadata. At that point, a second device cannot know about the seeded data from the first device.

Apple's advice is to handle this by de-deplicating your data after each merge. Each device just adds its own seed data, and if you find that it has been added twice, you delete half of it, being careful to ensure corresponding objects are deleted on each device.

This approach works, but feels a bit like a hack. An alternative, used in my [Ensembles](http://ensembles.io) framework, is to supply global identifiers for your objects so that the sync framework can automatically import and merge seed data. That is the approach taken in Ensembles, and it makes seeding data quite a bit easier and less ad hoc.